# Instead of delete trigger in SQL Server with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, triggers

I'm trying to create an instead of delete trigger in SQL Server which will check the value/quantity of an item in a second table before deleting the item from the first table. I have been unable to create a join between the tables. Can anyone identify what is wrong with my code? I'd appreciate any help.

```
CREATE TRIGGER  tr_delete_orders
ON orders
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
   DECLARE @del_qty INT

   SET @del_qty = orders.order_id
   FROM DELETED
   JOIN order_details ON order_details.order_id=orders.order_id

   IF (SELECT order_details.quantity FROM DELETED) >= 1
   BEGIN
        PRINT   'You may not delete items that have quantity in the order_detail table.'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
   END;
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `DELETE` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then the `Deleted` pseudo table will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SET @del_qty = orders.order_id  FROM DELETED` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get an arbitrary row, and all 24 others are ignored. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: You also need to be careful with a rollback inside a trigger. If the code doing the delete is expecting a transaction it will fail when the transaction is rolled back in the trigger. I would suggest using RAISERROR instead.

Comment: One more problem, you are joining DELETED to Order_details on order_details.order_id=orders.order_id.   You need to replace "orders" with "DELETED" since that is the table you are joining.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to delete only the orders that do not contain any order details (quantity = 0). Even though you plan to use the delete functionality per order, the trigger should be able to delete many orders (as pointed in the comments above).

```
CREATE TRIGGER  tr_delete_orders
ON orders
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
   delete o 
   from orders o inner join deleted d on d.order_id = o.order_id
   where not exists (select top 1 
                     from order_details od 
                     where od.order_id = o.order_id and od.quantity > 0)
```